# Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.jar
Required by:
    cap.libraries:opencv:unspecified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this answer
Replace with this :-classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'